OpenStack cannot (live) migrate instances - No hosts matched
I have a bunch of hypervisors, I want to drain 1 of the hypervisors, but I am unable to targeted migrate instances.
As an example:
$ openstack server show e6fb86c1-a03c-4960-a498-6c225cb2e941
| Field                               | Value                                                                                                                                                                                               |
+-------------------------------------+-------+
| OS-DCF:diskConfig                   | MANUAL                                                                                                                                                                                              |
| OS-EXT-AZ:availability_zone         | non-production                                                                                                                                                                                      |
| OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:host                | ab-c-07-09                                                                                                                                                                                          |
| OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:hostname            | instance05                                                                                                                                                                                           |
| OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:hypervisor_hostname | ab-c-07-09.sub.domain.com                                                                                                                                                                           |
| OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:instance_name       | instance-0000040f                                                                                                                                                                                   |
| OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:kernel_id           |                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
| OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:launch_index        | 0                                                                                                                                                                                                   |
| OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:ramdisk_id          |                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
| OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:reservation_id      | r-cspf0k2m                                                                                                                                                                                          |
| OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:root_device_name    | /dev/vda                                                                                                                                                                                            |
| OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:user_data           |                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
| OS-EXT-STS:power_state              | Running                                                                                                                                                                                             |
| OS-EXT-STS:vm_state                 | active                                                                                                                                                                                              |
| OS-SRV-USG:terminated_at            | None                                                                                                                                                                                                |
| accessIPv4                          |                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
| accessIPv6                          |                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
| addresses                           | VLAN1234=172.18.12.34                                                                                                                                                                              |
| config_drive                        |                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
| created                             | 2021-03-30T09:47:34Z                                                                                                                                                                                |
| flavor                              | description=, disk='32', ephemeral='0', , id='c4.2xlarge', is_disabled=, is_public='True', location=, name='c4.2xlarge', original_name='c4.2xlarge', ram='16384', rxtx_factor=, swap='0', vcpus='4' |
| hostId                              | d466872320362a37a50e04435df1409ea543a592392fbe53b7181987                                                                                                                                            |
| host_status                         | UP                                                                                                                                                                                                  |
| id                                  | e6fb86c1-a03c-4960-a498-6c225cb2e941                                                                                                                                                                |
| image                               | ubuntu 20.04 LTS (64d2a2b3-dc51-40d2-b19e-24484a8aced2)                                                                                                                                             |
| key_name                            | id_deploy                                                                                                                                                                                    |
| locked                              | False                                                                                                                                                                                               |
| locked_reason                       | None                                                                                                                                                                                                |
| name                                | instance05                                                                                                                                                                                           |
| pinned_availability_zone            | None                                                                                                                                                                                                |
| project_id                          | dc58584fc6104684873cf495c151a7b3                                                                                                                                                                    |
| properties                          |                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
| security_groups                     | name='wide-open'                                                                                                                                                                                    |
| server_groups                       | None                                                                                                                                                                                                |
| status                              | ACTIVE                                                                                                                                                                                              |
| tags                                |                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
| trusted_image_certificates          | None                                                                                                                                                                                                |
| updated                             | 2024-06-24T09:43:20Z                                                                                                                                                                                |
| user_id                             | ff8775cc4dd424c0d83c0b66cb1274ae6d8e25af2ff530dc100c938c3be9014e                                                                                                                                    |
| volumes_attached                    | delete_on_termination='False', id='13224ec3-832b-4a28-8fcb-7a9074f67274'                                                                                                                            |
|                                     | delete_on_termination='False', id='3313858e-d24a-4481-9d07-f7e43355c364'                                                                                                                            |

When performing a live migration, I am getting the following:
$ openstack server migrate --live-migration e6fb86c1-a03c-4960-a498-6c225cb2e941 --host ab-c-07-05 --os-compute-api-version 2.30
No valid host was found. There are not enough hosts available. (HTTP 400) (Request-ID: req-148a875d-2532-4496-b56e-b9e0ace84be0)

And in nova-scheduler.log the following is logged:
2024-06-24 13:00:08.506 215 INFO nova.scheduler.host_manager [req-148a875d-2532-4496-b56e-b9e0ace84be0 0844cf48c89650b3d49c323804a3f4427286abf390799d8ff4003f7c0e538edc 661a232f94924c0d8c77b1da492807a9 - a24a888f03b7427190e423c0fc45e54b a24a888f03b7427190e423c0fc45e54b] No hosts matched due to not matching requested destination (ab-c-07-05, ab-c-07-05.sub.domain.com)
2024-06-24 13:00:08.508 215 INFO nova.scheduler.host_manager [req-148a875d-2532-4496-b56e-b9e0ace84be0 0844cf48c89650b3d49c323804a3f4427286abf390799d8ff4003f7c0e538edc 661a232f94924c0d8c77b1da492807a9 - a24a888f03b7427190e423c0fc45e54b a24a888f03b7427190e423c0fc45e54b] Host filter ignoring hosts: 

This is the target hypervisor:
$ openstack hypervisor show ab-c-07-05.sub.domain.com
| Field                | Value                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              |
+----------------------+-------+
| aggregates           | ['DEV']                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            |
| cpu_info             | arch='x86_64', features='['pge', 'avx', 'xsaveopt', 'clflush', 'sep', 'rtm', 'tsc_adjust', 'tsc-deadline', 'dtes64', 'stibp', 'invpcid', 'tsc', 'intel-pt', 'fsgsbase', 'xsave', 'smap', 'vmx', 'erms', 'xtpr', 'cmov', 'hle', 'smep', 'ssse3', 'ds_cpl', 'est', 'pat', 'monitor', 'smx', 'pbe', 'lm', 'msr', 'adx', '3dnowprefetch', 'nx', 'fxsr', 'syscall',     |
|                      | 'tm', 'sse4.1', 'pae', 'sse4.2', 'pclmuldq', 'cx16', 'pcid', 'fma', 'vme', 'mmx', 'osxsave', 'cx8', 'mce', 'de', 'rdtscp', 'ht', 'dca', 'lahf_lm', 'abm', 'md-clear', 'popcnt', 'mca', 'pdpe1gb', 'apic', 'sse', 'f16c', 'pse', 'ds', 'invtsc', 'pni', 'tm2', 'avx2', 'aes', 'sse2', 'ss', 'rdrand', 'arat', 'bmi1', 'bmi2', 'acpi', 'spec-ctrl', 'fpu', 'ssbd',   |
|                      | 'pse36', 'mtrr', 'movbe', 'pdcm', 'x2apic', 'rdseed']', model='Broadwell-IBRS', topology.cells='2', topology.cores='8', topology.sockets='1', topology.threads='2', vendor='Intel'                                                                                                                                                                                 |
| disk_available_least | 198842                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             |
| free_disk_gb         | 502077                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             |
| free_ram_mb          | 66877                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              |
| hypervisor_hostname  | ab-c-07-05.sub.domain.com                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          |
| hypervisor_type      | QEMU                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               |
| hypervisor_version   | 2012000                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            |
| id                   | a10357f6-1103-4c86-8cc8-a821fa09b235                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               |
| local_gb             | 502397                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             |
| local_gb_used        | 320                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                |
| memory_mb            | 128829                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             |
| memory_mb_used       | 61952                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              |
| running_vms          | 3                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  |
| service_host         | ab-c-07-05                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         |
| service_id           | c688665a-fede-4b2f-9917-06fe6519f159                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               |
| state                | up                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 |
| status               | enabled                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            |
| vcpus                | 32                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 |
| vcpus_used           | 24                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 |

Source hypervisor:
$ openstack hypervisor show ab-c-07-09.sub.domain.com
| Field                | Value                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              |
+----------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| aggregates           | ['DEV']                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            |
| cpu_info             | arch='x86_64', features='['pge', 'avx', 'xsaveopt', 'clflush', 'sep', 'rtm', 'tsc_adjust', 'tsc-deadline', 'dtes64', 'stibp', 'invpcid', 'tsc', 'intel-pt', 'fsgsbase', 'xsave', 'smap', 'vmx', 'erms', 'xtpr', 'cmov', 'hle', 'smep', 'ssse3', 'ds_cpl', 'est', 'pat', 'monitor', 'smx', 'pbe', 'lm', 'msr', 'adx', '3dnowprefetch', 'nx', 'fxsr', 'syscall',     |
|                      | 'tm', 'sse4.1', 'pae', 'sse4.2', 'pclmuldq', 'cx16', 'pcid', 'fma', 'vme', 'mmx', 'osxsave', 'cx8', 'mce', 'de', 'rdtscp', 'ht', 'dca', 'lahf_lm', 'abm', 'md-clear', 'popcnt', 'mca', 'pdpe1gb', 'apic', 'sse', 'f16c', 'pse', 'ds', 'invtsc', 'pni', 'tm2', 'avx2', 'aes', 'sse2', 'ss', 'rdrand', 'arat', 'bmi1', 'bmi2', 'acpi', 'spec-ctrl', 'fpu', 'ssbd',   |
|                      | 'pse36', 'mtrr', 'movbe', 'pdcm', 'x2apic', 'rdseed']', model='Broadwell-IBRS', topology.cells='2', topology.cores='8', topology.sockets='1', topology.threads='2', vendor='Intel'                                                                                                                                                                                 |
| disk_available_least | 198847                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             |
| free_disk_gb         | 502077                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             |
| free_ram_mb          | 54589                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              |
| hypervisor_hostname  | ab-c-07-09.sub.domain.com                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          |
| hypervisor_type      | QEMU                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               |
| hypervisor_version   | 2012000                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            |
| id                   | bc6ff1a2-1739-48de-ac1b-3e446c4e6205                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               |
| local_gb             | 502397                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             |
| local_gb_used        | 320                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                |
| memory_mb            | 128829                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             |
| memory_mb_used       | 74240                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              |
| running_vms          | 3                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  |
| service_host         | ab-c-07-09                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         |
| service_id           | 48124098-bc52-4ffd-8fcb-f595c5e205e3                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               |
| state                | up                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 |
| status               | enabled                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            |
| vcpus                | 32                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 |
| vcpus_used           | 24                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 |

As you can see the target hypervisor has the same CPU and enough resources, so what is the problem here? It is not just this VM or not just these hypervisors. This one is just an example out of a lot.
